# Does anyone have a term for hard to measure?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word or even idiom that means hard to give a tangible measurement, as in:

> The company's growth due to such as such improvement was hard to measure or "insert term or idiom here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say the company's growth is hard to *[quantify](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quantify)* (express or measure the quantitity of) or the company's growth is *[unquantifiable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unquantifiable)* (impossible to express or measure in terms of quantity) (Oxford Dictionary of English).